# Animation with Scale and bounce

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to set animation like : https://www.dropbox.com/s/ua2tj7jio64xap2/slideupanim.mov?dl=0

I have used below code to create slide up animation.Result what I get from this is : https://www.dropbox.com/s/uggcktccjivlknk/device-2018-05-18-183937.mp4?dl=0

**Issue** : It is not bouncing with some extra scale value.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<translate
    android:duration="350"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator"
    android:toYDelta="0%"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:duration="350"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"

        android:toYDelta="0%"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solve my animation by below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator">

    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set>
```

Hope this will works for you.